# php filter validate email

Tags: php, html

trying to do validation for email using filter_validate_email. and use meth post. however, I get an error that

> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   H:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Walkthrough-Completed\register.php on line 68

E-mail is not valid

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Type your email"><span id="emailError"></span>
<?php
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
     echo("E-mail is not valid");
  }
  else
  {
     echo("E-mail is valid");
  }     
?>
```

Comment: How you're getting `$email` it is obviously not defined anywhere.

Comment: Why not use type="email" in the input? That way you get a first filter of the input

Comment: assign value or define $email like  $email = $_POST["email"];
befor using filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On same page you are posting data & checking posting data validation.To achieve this you have to ad post condition :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
     echo("E-mail is not valid");
  }
  else
  {
     echo("E-mail is valid");
  }     
}
?>
```